# Using enable_if to change function declaration between pass by value vs pass by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, enable-if

I am writing a templated hashmap.
For I want a function declarations to be pass by reference if the templated type is fundemental.

For example with the following declaration:

```
template<typename K,
         typename V,
         typename Hasher    = DEFAULT_HASH_32<K>,
         typename Allocator = DEFAULT_MMAP_ALLOC<K, V>>
class my_table {

...

int add(K const & key, V const & val);
};

...

template<typename K, typename V, typename Hasher, typename Allocator>
int
my_table<K, V, Hasher, Allocator>::add(K const & key, V const & val)
```

I want to be able to switch between passing either K or V as reference or as value depending on what would be optimal given the type.

I know that I could have duplicates of the `int add(...)` function but I am wondering if there is a way to only change the declaration without having to have copies of the exact same function.

Obviously the following pseudo code would not work, but it should give a clear idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
#if is_fundemental<K> && is_fundemental<V>
int add(K key, V val);
#elif is_fundemental<K> && !is_fundemental<V>
int add(K key, V const & val);
#elif !is_fundemental<K> && is_fundemental<V>
int add(K const & key, V val);
#else
int add(K const & key, V const & val);
#endif

// then at the functions implementation
#if is_fundemental<K> && is_fundemental<V>
int add(K key, V val) {
#elif is_fundemental<K> && !is_fundemental<V>
int add(K key, V const & val) {
#elif !is_fundemental<K> && is_fundemental<V>
int add(K const & key, V val) {
#else
int add(K const & key, V const & val) {
#endif
```

Thanks!

Edit:Piotr Skotnicki has an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use SFINAE for something as simple as changing a signature. Instead, use some basic *call-traits* that adjust the parameter type:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename K, typename V>
class my_table
{
    template <typename T>
    using param_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_fundamental_v<T>, T, const T&>;

public:
    int add(param_type<K> key, param_type<V> val);
};

template <typename K, typename V>
int my_table<K, V>::add(param_type<K> key, param_type<V> val)
{
    return {};
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5117d2719b75e834)

---

Here's a [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) definition of the alias:

```
template <typename T>
using param_type = typename std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<T>::value
                                           , T
                                           , const T&>::type;
```

Comment: This works for c++17 (thank you this is 100% more elegant that what I was thinking). Is there by chance a way to do this with c++11 you know of?

Comment: Is there a reason for const T& as opposed to T const& ?

Comment: @Noah No difference. Just style.